# css Issue after upgrade to Angular 12 from 8

Tags: html, css, angular

I have just upgraded my application from Angular 8 and 12 along with bootstrap. I made the required fixes but 2 has me stumped.

This is how my HTML is suppose to look

[image]

This is how it looks now after upgrade

[image]

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border-fieldset h-100">
            <legend style="font-size: small;">&#160;Site Type&#160;</legend>  
            <div class="row">
               .
               .
               .
            </div>
        </p-fieldset>
    </div>  
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .scheduler-border-fieldset {
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1.4em 0.4em 1.4em !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #333333;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

legend  {
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #aeccea;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Bootstrap version before upgrade was 4.5.0 After upgrade is Bootstrap v5.1.2

I cannot figure how i can fix the css so that the border fieldset runs through the legend and not bordering the legend.

Comment: The issue is probably with Bootstrap, which you haven't tagged. Please do, or revise to tell us the before and after versions.

Comment: Quick fix, just add `legend { position: relative; top: -10px; }`

Comment: @skobaljic thanks u so much.